# CRC32 endianess swapped

Tags: crc32

I have two functions to calculate CRC32:

1)

```
for (loop = 0u; loop < len; ++loop)
{
    crc = lut[((uint8_t)(crc >> 24) ^ data[loop])] ^ (crc << 8u);
}
```

2. 

```
for (i = 0u; i < len; i++)
{
    crc = lut[((uint32_t)data[i] ^ crc) & 0xFFu] ^ (crc >> 8u);
}
```

Both can calculate the same result but:

- lookup table for second one has vales with different Endianess
- After calculation result also has swapped endianess

The question is why there are two different implementations? Is there a specific name for calculation like in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

They are clearly equivalent after byte-swapping the results of one of them, if the table is also byte swapped.

Normally I see those two forms of CRC calculation for *different* CRCs, because one is using a bit-reflected polynomial (the code with `>>`), and the other with a normal polynomial ("<<").

However I have not seen a case where someone took one of those and then byte-swapped the table and switched from "<<" to ">>" or vice versa. I don't think there is a name for that.

The application I might imagine for such a thing is that someone had to byte swap the result at the end in order to make it easier to put the CRC in some predefined format They then realized they could avoid the byte swap if instead they built that into the table and the direction of shifting when computing.